# how i disabled performance underline in flutter android studio

Tags: flutter, dart

[I want to remove that green underline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSL4o.png)

I tried to use 'const' before widgets but sometimes i do not want to use it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Flutter or Dart, but assuming that is an Intellij IDE, there should be a way to disable that inspection in the settings. When you hover over it, a lightbulb is likely to appear - if you click on that, it might also have an option to disable the warning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple change

**/analysis_options.YAML and adding prefer_const_constructors: false on the rules field**